# proving convergence and finding the limit of this sequence if it is convergent?

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

$a(n)=\sin(1+a(n-1))$ where $a(0)=0$ and $n$ belongs to integers , prove or disprove whether the sequence converges and find the limit .
well i understood that this is bounded but i am not able to prove that it is monotonically increasing to show that it will be convergent . i am able to see it will converge and its limit will be solution of $x=\sin(1+x)$ but i am not able to prove this rigorously .
thanks for your help

Comment: You mean the sequence.

Comment: yes , i meant the sequence

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal do you know the solution for this

Comment: I recommand you to study the sequence $a(n)=\sin(n)$ to see what's going on.

Comment: You're trying to prove that the solution to $x=\sin(1+x)$ is an *attractive fixed point* of the function $f(x)=\sin(1+x)$. The reason this is true is because $|f'(x)|<1$ at this fixed point.